# updating an empty date/time field and a status(varchar) field simultaneous with a single query in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

im designing a web portal to monitor the distribution of voters cards and im having a little issue with my database query. i want to be able to track the exact time each card is issued using the mysql built in NOW() statement by issuing a query that will save update the date and time field and simultaneously update another field on the same row in my database but my query doesn't seem to work. please i need help, check out my sql query below

```
$query = "UPDATE PVC_Issuance SET current_status = 'collected', date_&_time_issued = NOW() WHERE VIN = '$VIN'";
```

note this code works if i take of "date_&_time_issued = NOW()" from the query but gives no output if i include it

please i need help asap.... thanks in advance

Comment: have you tried adding mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error()); to see what the actual error is?

Comment: Try adding ticks around the `date_&_time_issued` column. `&` is a operator, and is a "reserved keyword".

Comment: thanks scrum it worked, i had to rename the column date_time_issued without the & operator i guess sql was misinterpreting my query....

Answer (score -1):

if the Column `date_&_time_issued` Type is DATETIME this is maybe the problem so you should change it to VARCHAR or INT

Comment: -1 `NOW()` (the value which is he is updating to) is a `DATETIME`